# Is it possible to use Transactional with CompletableFuture

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, transactions

I am getting this exception (Sometime it works and sometime fails)

---

> HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

I am trying to save two entities in database with Transactional, here is the pseudo code:

```
@Override  
@Transactional  
public CompletableFuture<String> commit(MyRequest request) {   
  String documentCode = "dummy-id";
  return commit(documentCode, request)
    .thenApply(
        taxResult -> {
          saveSecondEntity(taxResult); // Exception here
          return documentCode;
        })
        .exceptionally(
                throwable -> {
                  // org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
                  logThrowable(request, throwable);

                  return null;
                });
}
```

Further I checked that `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()` returns `false` inside `saveSecondEntity` method and thread name is also different.

Is it possible to use Transactional with `CompletableFuture`?

Answer (score 1):

You're starting a transaction with `@Transactional` but you're executing `saveSecondEntity` from another thread. Generally J2EE/Spring won't let you create your own threads because the container manages them: internally things such as transactions or security are tied to a thread.

On top of that Hibernate sessions (and the underlying JDBC connection) are not thread safe, so it is not a good idea to do it this way